# NPM error while running npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, npm-install

When I run `npm install`

```sh
PS D:\reactprojects\pinterestclone> npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: pinterestclone@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.8.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react        
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material       
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR!   1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:        
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report. 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-02T14_38_20_119Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Can you also show your `package.json` file?

Comment: {
  "name": "pinterestclone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `--force` after your install command. Because React 18 was just launched some libraries can't find a way to fit in properly. Run this command

```sh
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI and React Js are updating something and for now it's not compatible so you just need to add --force after every command you enter.